# Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem for even-dimensional manifolds with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, characteristic-classes

On the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) for the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem it states that there is a generalization of the theorem for even-dimensional manifolds with boundary, but does not provide the relevant theorem or any reference. The [nlab page](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gauss-Bonnet+theorem) also does not mention the case of a manifold with boundary. Could someone point me to a source which discusses the case with nonempty boundary?

Comment: Theorem 1.8 on Page 86  here might have what you're looking for.  http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf

Comment: @KajHansen nice find. I think this is also in O'neill. See the Gauss Bonnet section, I'm running out the door, but it's easy enough to find the first edition pdf legally online.

Comment: @ Kaj Hansen the theorem given on page 86 is the plain old Gauss-Bonnet theorem for surfaces. I'm looking for the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem, which applies to manifolds of any even dimension.

Comment: I figured that'd be your complaint @ಠ_ಠ.  At least I tried. :P

Comment: It looks essentially the same. See theorem 4.4 [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~alanw/240papers00/zhu.pdf).

Comment: There is a comment in Lee about a generalization in terms of a Pfaffian in higher dimension of which the geometric interpretation is not currently known, I wonder if that is the same as what is linked by Mike Miller.

Comment: @ Mike Miller, thanks, just what I was looking for! Looks like the theorem is given in one of Spivak's volumes according to the references given.